# Неправильно работает функция rand() в c++

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

     int v1 = rand() % 10;
     cout << "1" << v1 << endl;
     cout << "2" << 1 + rand() % 5 << endl;
     cout << "3" << 1 + rand() % 5 << endl;
     cout << "4" << 1 + rand() % 5 << endl;
     cout << "5" << 1 + rand() % 5 << endl;
     cout << "6" << 1 + rand() % 5 << endl;
     cout << "7" << 1 + rand() % 5 << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Хочу получить рандомные числа от 0 до 5. Этот код возвращает:
11
23
35
41
55
65
74
Почему?

Comment: Функция `rand()` устарела, пользуйтесь https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Пробел поставьте

Comment: O_o. Так вы же сами печатаете `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`  и т.д. перед своим числом...

Comment: @Slava: Это где и кто сказал, что "функция rand() устарела"?

Comment: @AnT https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/61587

Comment: Спасибо. Понялю

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89006/discussion-on-question-by------ran).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шутить изволите?

Вы выводите цифру, за которой сразу после пробела следует случайное число:

```
 cout << "2" << 1 + rand() % 5 << endl;
```

После этого ваше 23 следует рассматривать как "2", за которой выведено 3, которое и есть ваше случайное число от 1 до 5 :)

Первое число `v1` у вас 1, затем вы получаете 3 5 1 5 5 4.

Но я бы рекомендовал - раз уж у вас C++ - ознакомиться с библиотекой `<random>`, генерирующей случайные числа более "по-взрослому" :)